# How do I gradually(feather/gradient/transition) blur in CSS?

Tags: css, gradient, blur

I want to slowly transition from 0% blur to 100% blur.

Ideally, I could use the linear gradient syntax `backdrop-filter: linear-gradient(blur(8px), blur(8px), blur(0));` but that doesn't seem to be supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `mask` on any filter (`filter` and `backdrop-filter`). This will let you progressively blur content.

[image]

eg. https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/jOBxGjr

```
mask: linear-gradient(black, black, transparent);
backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
```

Support is there. <strike>with the exception of Firefox for "backdrop-filter", as of June 5, 2021.</strike>

https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter